# In a Dockerfile is possible to not override the base image CMD when implementing my own CMD?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I find that if I implement my own CMD, when I run a container with my derived image, I lost all the functionality provided by the base image.
Inclusive, my container doesn't keep running if I put a CMD in the derived Dockerfile....
How to reuse the same ENTRYPOINT and CMD from a base image, just adding more commands?
I want to do that because I want to run certain commands every time I run a new container.
(That sounds right?)

Example:
php:7.4.7-apache

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-php-entrypoint"]

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/b6fd2f70018163227f0f18f3ba1fa4d70e6d929e/7.4/buster/apache

Comment: A Docker container only runs one command.  That could be a script that launches other things (or manually runs a base image's command), but there's no way to "add commands".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker only runs one command when a container is starting and if you have a base image and a derived image, it will run the command from the derived image. Or if you override the command while using docker run command / use a different command in docker-compose, it will take priority over the command defined inside the image.

You can create a shell file or any executable file (like python file if python is available in the container) to execute any number of commands and run this file during container startup using a bash shell (or any other shell that's available in the container).